# SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .Net Data Provider, reason code 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, db2

I am getting the following error trying to connect to a local DB2 instance with Entity Framework using Visual Studio 2010:

> SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .Net Data Provider, reason code
>   7, tokens 9.7.3.DEF.2, SOFTWARE\IBM\DB2\InstalledCopies

I have tried to do some research and gotten nowhere, but I assume there is an issue with the DB2 Provider that I am using (I got the newest from IBM). I am able to hit the data if I use `IBM.DB2.Data` Namespace using the dll from IBM, but I cant hit the database using the Entity Model Wizard.

I dont have a problem hitting this DB from Visual Studio 2008, do I need to download something else other than what I have?

My DB2 Control Center says

DB2 administration tools level:
Product identifier           SQL09070

Level identifier             08010107

Level                        DB2 v9.7.0.441

Build level                  s090521

PTF                          NT3297

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless something changed recently, that last I remember you can't use the entity framework directly with the IBM drivers. You need to write the interface yourself to get this to work. As I said, this is what my research turned up a couple months ago when I was researching this.